# Dynammically create ImageViews not showing the image

Tags: android, imageview

I have a custom adapter for a `listview` and here is the getView method;

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) JourneyPlannerActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.journey_planner_route_detail, viewGroup, false);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.journey_planner_detail_detail_main_id);

            JourneyPlannerRoute r = m_Routes.get(i);
            String directions = "";
            for(int j=0 ; j < r.getRoutes().size() ; j++){
                ImageView image = new ImageView(JourneyPlannerActivity.this);
                String transportMethod = r.getRoutes().get(j).getMeansOfTransport();
                if(transportMethod.equals("Train"))
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.network_rail_logo);
                else if(transportMethod.equals("Subway"))
                    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundel_tube);
                else if(transportMethod.equals("Bus"))
                    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bus);
                else if(transportMethod.equals("Walk"))
                    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.walking);
                image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layout.addView(image);
                //directions += r.getRoutes().get(j).getMeansOfTransport()+",";
            }
            directions += " "+r.getDuration();

            TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.journey_planner_detail_main_text_view);
            tv.setText(directions);

            return rowView;
```

After going through the debug it seems the imageviews are being added to the layout but they're just not appearing on the screen;

[image]

I had a feeling it was due to not picking up the correct layout but it seems as though it is?!

Here is the xml file for the row;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/journey_planner_detail_detail_main_id">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/bus_small"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/journey_planner_detail_main_text_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add xml code for the item layout?

Comment: Sorry, knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating new Image view just call `rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);` (you'll have to add id to the xml).

The actual bug is with the `TextView`. It is set to `fill_parent` causing the newly added `ImageView` to appear to the right of the visible screen. You can change this by changind the `TextView` width to `wrap_content`. However, using the `ImageView` defined in xml layout is better.

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't even considering my layout, silly man! Thanks again, I'll accept when I can.